# Scaling and performance SQL or NoSQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, scaling

I have read a few mini books on the use of NoSQL such as CouchDB or MongoDB (the latter of which I am more familiar).

What would be more appropriate in terms of performance - especially scaling:

1. Individual DB's hosted on distinct servers if needed
2. A single MongoDB partitioned using sharding

I left out SQL scaling techniques such as master-slave (which is what I understand is the way you scale SQL with applications that out-grow their servers).

Each "account" in my application will be for personal use only and won't likely grow to insane sizes or access. So I figure I could have the application hosted on one or a few servers with the data spread out across one or more servers as required. When one SQL tapped out I would relocate half (proportionally speaking in terms of usage) of the DB's to another server (remote or not). This should in theory provide some performance boost allowing to me scale somewhat with little effort???

Alternatively sharing in NoSQL solutions sounds pretty easy - the only side effect being I need to keep all records in a singe database - decreasing individual security a slight - in theory?

What are your experiences/opinions on this matter?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit confusing. You are asking about performance characteristics of two different scalability approaches... which makes the assumption that the two scalability approaches are fairly equivalent, which they are not.

There are two different approaches you've asked about here; I'll describe them using standard terms. These are not NoSQL specific and apply to really any technology.

Vertical scaling which is a very large single server.

Horizontal scaling which is many smaller servers clustered together.

These two solutions are as different as they come. Horizontal scaling enables the ability to gradually add capacity with a consistent small cost. Vertical scaling requires a very large cost upfront and again each time the capacity of the single server is full. All other things aside, it is usually because of this factor that horizontal scaling is the approach architects use to scale. Google proved the viability of this approach in the late 90s.

MongoDB and other NoSQL solutions use this approach to achieve scalability. In MongoDB it's called sharding. Now to address performance characteristics. In the vertical approach what ends up happening to grow in capacity is that this single machine is actually itself a series of clustered components. Giant hard drive arrays, arrays of motherboards and cpus and ram. It's impossible to contrast the two, because so much of it is dependent on the actual hardware and environment used. One thing is clear though. To achieve a similar amount of performance, the horizontal approach will be less expensive and less complex.

There are a few benefits to the horizontal approach as well. Some natural limits occur on a single machine which are avoided by splitting the load across many machines.

Lastly, on a side note, Master / Slave is not used to scale. It multiplies all writes at the sake of providing more read capacity. This means that each additional node provides less and less benefit. While it can increase read capacity slightly, it is intended for high availability, not scale.

Comment: I don't I fully expressed myself previous,l pardon my mistake :)

What I intnded to ask is whether separating every users data onto a distinct DB (thus possible server - either virtual or physical) would obtain similar scaling results to sharding? Is this not something like scaling horizontally? If each user could run their own distinct database, I could in theory balance the load of SQL across any number of cheap servers?